# How to add List[String] values to a single column in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe, I have a list of values (possibly list string) and I want to create a new column in my dataframe and add those list values as column values to this new column. I tried

```
val x = List("def", "cook", "abc")
val c_df = null
x.foldLeft(c_df)((df, column) => df.withColumn("newcolumnname" , lit(column)))
```

but it throws `StackOverflow` exception, I also tried iterating over list of string values and adding to dataframe but result value is a list of dataframe but all i want is a single dataframe.

Please help!

here is the sample input and output dataframe:
[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample output of how you expect your dataframe to look like? Also are you attempting to create a new dataframe or expanding on an existing one?

Comment: I am trying to add new column to an existing dataframe, just need a way to add list of string to that new column i added

Comment: Hi Jimmy, what I understood is you would like to add the list of values to existing DataFrame in a separate column? Is it correct?

Comment: @neerajbhadani, thatz exactly what I want, can u plz help

Comment: do you want to have a new column per value? Or just a single column with 3 rows?

Comment: @AKSW, I want to add new column "some name" to existing dataframe I have with values from List[String] or List[Any] which I have.So that means  a single column with rows as no of items in my list

Comment: But how should this work? What if the dataframe has 4 rows?

Comment: @AKSW, how should I iterate over df, get a value of particular column and add that value to this new column, that way I can have exact number of rows in that new column

Comment: Can you post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? with the error message that you are receiving please so we can help.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your goal. Please provide a minimal input and output dataframe

Comment: @AKSW , asume I have a dataframe1 with 10 columns and 100 rows, now what I want is to create a new column in this existing dataframe1, and values to this new column should be extracted from values of column 2, column3 of dataframe1, values I somehow extracted from column2, column3 and put them inside a list, now all i want is add this list to this new column of  dataframe1, lets assume its list[string] only, also assume dataframe1 has 100 rows, but this list size is 100, so these 100 items inside list I want to add to this new column of datafram1.

Comment: Can you just provide a sample input and desired output, it is not clear, I might not be able to help you :/

Comment: Here is the input dataframe:

Comment: @guys I added sample input and output dataframe to my question, plz check

I already have List[String, List[Strings]] as List[newColumnName, List[Columnvalues]

Comment: @JimmyMaguel Do you have 4 records with new records having null values for the name, degree, salary and address ?

Comment: You should also copy and paste it instead of using an image

Comment: yes @Constantine

Comment: @here, nothing is working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

1. Create First DataFrame with Index.

> ```
> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
> from pyspark.sql import Window
> w = Window.orderBy("Col2")
> df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 10), ("b", 20), ("c",  30)], ["Col1", "Col2"])
> df1 = df.withColumn("index", row_number().over(w))
> df1.show()
> ```

2. Create Another DataFrame from List of Values.

> ```
> from pyspark.sql.types import * newdf = spark.createDataFrame(['x','y', 'z'], StringType()) newdf.show()
> ```

3. Add Index column to DF created from List of values in step 2.

> ```
>  w = Window.orderBy("value")
> df2 = newdf.withColumn("index", row_number().over(w))
> df2.show()
> ```

4. Join the DataFrame df1 and df2 based on index.

> `df1.join(df2, "index").show()`

Comment: its in python, do u have scala version plz

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `array` in Spark 1.4 or later that takes an array of `Column`s and returns a new `Column`. Function `lit` takes a Scala value and returns a `Column` type.

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF("col1")
df.withColumn("new_col", array(lit("def"), lit("cook"), lit("abc"))).show

+----+----------------+
|col1|         new_col|
+----+----------------+
|   1|[def, cook, abc]|
|   2|[def, cook, abc]|
|   3|[def, cook, abc]|
+----+----------------+
```

In Spark 2.2.0, there is a function `typedLit` that takes Scala types and returns a `Column` type. this function can handle parameterized scala types e.g.: List, Seq and Map.

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("new_col", typedLit(List("def", "cook", "abc")))
newDF.show()
newDF.printSchema()

+----+----------------+
|col1|         new_col|
+----+----------------+
|   1|[def, cook, abc]|
|   2|[def, cook, abc]|
|   3|[def, cook, abc]|
+----+----------------+

root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- new_col: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

This is what you wanted to do ? You can add `when` to conditionally add different set of lists to each row.

Comment: instead of duplicating array, i wanted in col 1 value as def, in col2 cook and in col3 abc only

Comment: in new_col data is getting duplicated in ur answer

Comment: Adding to @ryandam answer:
df.withColumn("new_col", typedLit(List("def", "cook", "abc"))).withColumn("col1", new_col(0)).withColumn("col2", new_col(1)).withColumn("col3", new_col(2)).drop("new_col")